# Python : serialise class hierarchy

Tags: python, class, serialization, hierarchy

**I have to serialise a dynamically created class hierarchy.** And a bunch of objects - instances of the latter classes.

Python pickle is not of big help, its wiki says "Classes ... cannot be pickled". O there may be some trick that I cannot figure.

Performance requirement:

Deserialization should be pretty fast, because the serialised staff serves for cache and should save me the work of creating the same class hierarchy.

Details:

classes are created dynamically using type and sometimes meta-classes.

Comment: You have instances of the classes, you can pickle those **just fine**.

Comment: It is the classes themselves, which Pickle expects to load from source. If you are generating the classes themselves in a way that makes them not loadable from an import, then you cannot use pickle.

Comment: If you can do `from module import classname`, even dynamically created classes can be pickled.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters No, I have no module containing classes, I build them dynamically, their names, attributes, everything

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you explain? I need the classes as classes - to be able to produce more objects at run-time. And already created objects - as objects.

Comment: If you created classes dynamically then you'll need to devise a method to recreate those from serialized information instead, then deserialize the instances. That'll be an entirely custom job, one that *perhaps* could be handled by the [`object.__reduce__()` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__); it gives you a lot of flexibility on how *unpickling* is handled; e.g. it is no longer a requirement that the class itself can be imported.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a custom [`object.__reduce__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) I believe you can still use pickling.

Normally, when pickling, the class import path is stored, plus instance state. On unpickling, the class is imported, and a new instance is created using the stored state. This is why pickling cannot work with dynamic classes, there is nothing to import.

The `object.__reduce__()` method lets you store a **different** instance factory. The callable returned by this function is stored (again by import path), and called with specified arguments to produce an instance. This instance is then used to apply state to, in the same way a regular instance would be unpickled:

```
def class_factory(name):
    return globals()[name]()

class SomeDynamicClass(object):
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (class_factory, (type(self).__name__,), self.__dict__)
```

Here `__reduce__` returns a function, the arguments for the function, and the instance state.

All you need to do then, is provide the right arguments to the factory function to recreate the class, and return an instance of that class. It'll be used instead of importing the class directly.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are normal python objects, so, in theory, should be picklable, if you provide `__reduce__` (or implement other pickle protocol methods) for them.  Try to define `__reduce__` on their *metaclass*.